# Showing string in formula and not as variable in lm fit

Tags: r, formula, lm

I am not able to resolve the issue that when `lm(sformula)` is executed, it does not show the string that is assigned to `sformula`. I have a feeling it is generic way R handles argument of a function and not specific to linear regression.

Below is the illustration of the issue through examples. Example 1, has the **undesired** output `lm(formula = sformula)`. The example 2 is the output I would like i.e., `lm(formula = "y~x")`.

```
x <- 1:10
y <- x * runif(10)
sformula <- "y~x"

## Example: 1 
lm(sformula)

## Call:
## lm(formula = sformula)

## Example: 2
lm("y~x")

## Call:
## lm(formula = "y~x")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `eval(call("lm", sformula))`?

```
lm(sformula)
#Call:
#lm(formula = sformula)

eval(call("lm", sformula))
#Call:
#lm(formula = "y~x")
```

Generally speaking there is a `data` argument for `lm`. Let's do:

```
mydata <- data.frame(y = y, x = x)
eval(call("lm", sformula, quote(mydata)))
#Call:
#lm(formula = "y~x", data = mydata)
```

---

The above `call()` + `eval()` combination can be replaced by `do.call()`:

```
do.call("lm", list(formula = sformula))
#Call:
#lm(formula = "y~x")

do.call("lm", list(formula = sformula, data = quote(mydata)))
#Call:
#lm(formula = "y~x", data = mydata)
```