# How to match a data frame of variable names and another with data for a regression?

Tags: r, regression, formula, linear-regression, lm

I have two data frames:

```
x = data.frame(Var1= c("A", "B", "C", "D","E"),Var2=c("F","G","H","I","J"),
    Value= c(11, 12, 13, 14,18))

y = data.frame(A= c(11, 12, 13, 14,18), B= c(15, 16, 17, 14,18),C= c(17, 22, 23, 24,18), D= c(11, 12, 13, 34,18),E= c(11, 5, 13, 55,18),  F= c(8, 12, 13, 14,18),G= c(7, 5, 13, 14,18),
    H= c(8, 12, 13, 14,18), I= c(9, 5, 13, 14,18), J= c(11, 12, 13, 14,18))

Var3 <- rep("time", each=length(x$Var1))

x=cbind(x,Var3)

time=seq(1:length(y[,1]))
y=cbind(y,time)
```

---

```
> x
  Var1 Var2 Value Var3
1    A    F    11 time
2    B    G    12 time
3    C    H    13 time
4    D    I    14 time
5    E    J    18 time
> y
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J time
1 11 15 17 11 11  8  7  8  9 11    1
2 12 16 22 12  5 12  5 12  5 12    2
3 13 17 23 13 13 13 13 13 13 13    3
4 14 14 24 34 55 14 14 14 14 14    4
5 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18    5
```

Looking at `x` DF, I have variable `A` and `F` as the first row. I want to select these two variables in `y` DF and implement a simple regression: `lm(A ~ F, data = y)`, and save the result in the first position of a list. I will do the same with the second row of `x` DF implementing a regression `lm(B ~ G, data = y)`.

How could I match variables names in `x` to data in `y` for a regression?

---

**Revised question:** how about a more complicated regression `Var1 ~ Var2 + Var3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = data.frame(Var1= c("A", "B", "C", "D","E"),
               Var2=c("F","G","H","I","J"),
               Value= c(11, 12, 13, 14,18))

y = data.frame(A= c(11, 12, 13, 14,18),
               B= c(15, 16, 17, 14,18),
               C= c(17, 22, 23, 24,18),
               D= c(11, 12, 13, 34,18),
               E= c(11, 5, 13, 55,18),
               F= c(8, 12, 13, 14,18),
               G= c(7, 5, 13, 14,18),
               H= c(8, 12, 13, 14,18), 
               I= c(9, 5, 13, 14,18),
               J= c(11, 12, 13, 14,18))
```

We can use

```
fitmodel <- function (RHS, LHS) do.call("lm", list(formula = reformulate(RHS, LHS),
                                              data = quote(y)))

modList <- Map(fitmodel, as.character(x$Var2), as.character(x$Var1))

modList[[1]]  ## for example
#Call:
#lm(formula = A ~ F, data = y)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            F  
#     4.3500       0.7115
```

**Remarks:**

1. The use of `do.call` is to ensure that `reformulate` is evaluated when passed to `lm`. This is desired as it allows functions like `update` to work correctly on the model object. See [Showing string in formula and not as variable in lm fit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38558523/4891738). For a comparison:

   ```
   oo <- Map(function (RHS, LHS) lm(reformulate(RHS, LHS), data = y),
             as.character(x$Var2), as.character(x$Var1))
   oo[[1]]
   #Call:
   #lm(formula = reformulate(RHS, LHS), data = y)
   #
   #Coefficients:
   #(Intercept)            F  
   #     4.3500       0.7115
   ```
2. The `as.character` on `x$Var1` and `x$Var2` is necessary, as these two variables are currently "factor" variables not strings and `reformulate` can't use them. If you put `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame` when you build your `x`, there is no such issue.

> It works for you? It's not suppose to have a "for" loop?

The `Map` function hides that "for" loop. It is a wrapper of the `mapply` function. The `*apply` family functions in R are [a syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2275896/4891738).

---

### Update on your revised question

Your original question is constructs a model formula as `Var1 ~ Var2`.

Your new question wants `Var1 ~ Var2 + Var3`.

```
x$Var3 <- rep("time", each=length(x$Var1))
y$time <- seq(1:length(y[,1]))

## collect multiple RHS variables (using concatenation function `c`)
RHS <- Map(base::c, as.character(x$Var2), as.character(x$Var3))
#str(RHS)
#List of 5  ## oh this list has names! annoying!!
# $ F: chr [1:2] "F" "time"
# $ G: chr [1:2] "G" "time"
# $ H: chr [1:2] "H" "time"
# $ I: chr [1:2] "I" "time"
# $ J: chr [1:2] "J" "time"
LHS <- as.character(x$Var1)
modList <- Map(fitmodel, RHS, LHS)  ## `fitmodel` function unchanged
modList[[1]]  ## for example
#Call:
#lm(formula = A ~ F + time, data = y)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            F         time  
#        5.6          0.5          0.5
```