# Looping ggplot2 multiple linear regression

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2, regression

I am trying to loop my multiple linear regression plot and summaries, but I keep encountering an error in R that states `Error: More than one expression parsed`. I am not sure how to fix this or if there is a better way to achieve what I want to do which is mainly:

1. Plot a multiple linear regression plot with `Group` as the colour
2. Get summary for each of the linear regression lines based on `Group`
3. Compute regression summary
4. Perform anova to determine differences

```
colNames <- names(df)[c(35:39)]
for(i in colNames){
  plt <- ggplot(df, 
aes_string(x=df$MachineLength, y=i, fill=df$Group, color=be_nlyl$Group)) + 
geom_smooth(method=lm) + 
geom_point(size = 2, alpha=0.7) + 
labs(title="Machine", subtitle = "Machine Type") + 
theme_bw() + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face="bold"), 
plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust=0.5))
  print(plt)
  lm_A <- lm(formula = i ~ MachineLength, data = subset(be_nlyl, Group == "A"))
  summary(lm_A) %>% print()
lm_B <- lm(formula = i ~ MachineLength, data = subset(be_nlyl, Group == "B"))
  summary(lm_B) %>% print()
  clz.lm <- lm(formula = i ~ Group + MachineLength + Group:MachineLength, data = df)
summary(clz.lm) %>% print()
  ano.lm <- Anova(lm(i ~ MachineLength*Group, data = df))
  print(ano.lm)
}
```

Anyone have ideas of how to implement above? Thank you!

Comment: `j <- as.symbol(i); lm_A <- eval(bquote(lm(formula = .(j) ~ MachineLength, data = subset(df, Group == "A"))))`

Comment: And your ggplot2 `aes` code is probably not correct either. Remove the `df$` from it and quote all variables except `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following :

1. Create lists of length `colNames` to store all the outputs so that instead of just printing the output we can store them as well.
2. Use `for` loop over the index of `colNames` instead of actual column names so that you can use that as an index to store the output for different objects.
3. `aes_string` has be deprecated so we use `.data` pronoun to pass column name as variable.
4. Use `sprintf` to create formula string which is passed in `lm` function.

```
library(ggplot2)

colNames <- names(df)[c(35:39)]
plt <- vector('list', length(colNames))
lm_A <- vector('list', length(colNames))
summary_lm_A <- vector('list', length(colNames))
summary_lm_B <- vector('list', length(colNames))
lm_B <- vector('list', length(colNames))
clz.lm <- vector('list', length(colNames))
summary_clz.lm <- vector('list', length(colNames))
ano.lm <- vector('list', length(colNames))

for(i in seq_along(colNames)) {
  var <- colNames[i]
  plt[[i]] <- ggplot(df, aes(MachineLength, .data[[var]], fill= Group, color= Group)) + 
               geom_smooth(method=lm) + 
               geom_point(size = 2, alpha=0.7) + 
               labs(title="Machine", subtitle = "Machine Type") + 
               theme_bw() + 
               theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face="bold"), 
                     plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust=0.5))
  lm_A[[i]] <- lm(sprintf('%s~MachineLength', var), data = subset(df, Group == "A"))
  summary_lm_A[[i]] <- summary(lm_A[[i]])
  lm_B[[i]] <- lm(sprintf('%s~MachineLength', var), data = subset(df, Group == "B"))
  summary_lm_B[[i]] <- summary(lm_B[[i]])
  clz.lm[[i]] <- lm(sprintf('%s~Group + MachineLength + Group:MachineLength', var), data = df)
  summary_clz.lm[[i]] <- summary(clz.lm[[i]])
  ano.lm[[i]] <- Anova(lm(sprintf('%s~MachineLength*Group', var), data = df))
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I just needed to update the `printf()` to `sprintf()` in 3rd last line to remove the error I got at first and the code ran perfect after! If there was a way to have the column name shown instead of `%s~` in the printed output, that would be great, right now it shows `Call: lm(formula = sprintf("%s~MachineLength", var), data = subset(df, Group == "Case"))` but not sure if can show `Call: lm(formula = sprintf("TypeA~MachineLength", var), data = subset(df, Group == "Case"))` instead?

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the `sprintf` typo. Changing that call is isn't straightforward. You have to use `eval` + `call` there. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558523/showing-string-in-formula-and-not-as-variable-in-lm-fit